# Gitolite remembers a repository that it shouldn't

Tags: git, version-control, gitolite, osx-server

We have gitolite and it keeps complaining an existing repository doesn't exist.

Even after I edited `gitolite.conf` and removed that repo from the config.
So I'm wondering why it 'remembers' that repo?

I checked my changes were pushed correctly.
The `$gituser/.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf` is equal to my local one.

The message doesn't come from the `gitolite.pm` script, the exact error message is

```
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '/Users/git/repositoires/IJslander.git'
```

For example when committing the gitolite-admin repo:

```
$ git commit -a -m "bogus space"
[master 675b4e1] bogus space
 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
$ git push
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 360 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '/Users/git/repositoires/IJslander.git'
To git@redacted.com:gitolite-admin
   935c304..675b4e1  master -> master
```

And I have `grep`ed the whole HDD and nowhere does it mention that repo (but it did mention a new one we tried to make to replace it):

```
~ git$ grep -ilR "IJslander" . 2> /dev/null 
./.bash_history
./.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf
./.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm
./.gitolite/logs/gitolite-2011-07.log
./.gitolite/logs/gitolite-2011-08.log
```

And this is from the conf:

```
~ git$ grep -iR "IJslander" .gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf 2> /dev/null 
repo    ijslander-ios
//the compiled conf file
~ git$ grep -iR "IJslander" .gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm 2> /dev/null 
'ijslander-ios' => {
```

All repos are under `git`'s `~`

Comment: What _exact commands_ are you running to cause that error message, and which machine are you running them on?

Comment: Added it in :) Thanks for helping me, by the way! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Okay, so in the local repo you are running the `push` from, not the gitolite server, are there references to IJslander in its `.git/config`?

Comment: No, in the local `.git/config` are no references to it. And there aren't any in any of the other local repos, either (same goes for remote, on the gitolite server). That is: I honestly can't find them. If you want to run anything just tell me, I'll run it and post output.

Comment: Does it show up when you ssh gitolite@yourserver?

Comment: @wlangstroth nope. Nowhere to be found :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem..
just backup my repository at server-side,
uninstall gitolite completely, ref [here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/1-INSTALL.html#_uninstalling_gitolite_completely)
and re-install gitolite

Answer (score 2):

The message should be from the `gitolite.pm` script:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#       getperms and setperms
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

sub get_set_perms
{
    my($repo_base_abs, $repo, $verb, $user) = @_;
    my ($creater, $dummy, $dummy2) = &repo_rights($repo_base_abs, $repo, "");
    die "$repo doesnt exist or is not yours\n" unless $user eq $creater;
```

You could modify the script on the server to at least display the repo and the other variables on the "`die`" message, and see that way what repo it still consider.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that message is generated from git itself, not gitolite.  Check your `.git/config` file in the repository you're running it from, and erase the appropriate entry.  Alternately, try running `git remote rm <name>`.

Comment: To be clear: I'd have to run that on the remote? (because remote: is complaining?)

Comment: No, you have a local repo complaining about not being able to find a remote, so you run it on the local repo.

Comment: Can you edit your question to post your grep results?  Add a `-l` to the command if the results are too long.

Comment: Can't edit my comment :( I'm at a loss. I tried looking on my local computer for any references, can't find anything, only some mentions of that project in my chatlogs.